# JS - Collect all letters between a character (:)

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm looking to convert certain words to icons depending on what is commented in node.

I need to convert a string like:

> This is my fav item :9044: and :456:

into a js array like:

```
[ 9044, 456 ]
```

I've tried various Regex ways online but none have resulted in the correct output.

Previous failed attempts:

### ------------------

```
var comment = 'This is my fav item :9044: and :456:';
comment.substring(comment.lastIndexOf(":")+1,comment.lastIndexOf(":"));

// ':'
```

[image]

### ------------------

```
var comment = 'This is my fav item :9044: and :456:';
comment.match(":(.*):");

// [ ':9044: and :456:', '9044: and :456' ]
```

[image]

### ------------------

```
var comment = 'This is my fav item :9044: and :456:';
comment.match(/:([^:]+):/);

// [ ':9044:', '9044' ]
```

[image]

Comment: Are the in-between characters always numbers?

Comment: Unfortunately they can be either numbers or words

Comment: Your last regex looks fine. You just need to make it global `g` and either use `.exec()` with a loop, or take advantage of `.replace()` with a callback.

Comment: ...actually, just making the regex global should be enough to make your last solution work. `/:([^:]+):/g` Except that you'd need to map the result to trim the colons away. `comment.match(regex).map(s => +s.slice(1, -1))`

Comment: If it can be numbers or words, then it would seem your result should be strings and not numbers.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `regex.exec`

```js
var input = 'This is my fav item :9044: and :456: and another match :abc:';

let regex = /:(\w+):/g;
let results = [];
let number;

while(number = regex.exec(input)) {
  results.push(number[1]);
}
 
console.log(results);

regex = /:\w+:/g;
results = input.match(regex).map(num => num.replace(/:/g, ''));
 
console.log(results);

// And it you want to cast numbers
results = input.match(regex).map(num => {
   num = num.replace(/:/g, '');
   return Number.isNaN(+num) ? num : +num;
});
 
console.log(results);
```

Comment: OP says it's not always numbers between the colons. I'd go with a non-greedy wildcard, eg `/:(.+?):/g`

Comment: Yeah. Maybe use: `/:(.+?):/g`
And then maybe a separate regex/algorithm to detect and cast numbers